# Picking up mail at the Post Office in Japan

Tags: japan, shopping, mail

I have some small packages that I need to pick up the first day I arrive in Sapporo. Some of them will be delivered by Amazon, but for some reason convenience store pickup is not available. My Airbnb host will not be at home to receive them either.

The instructions for Kyoku-dome are at https://www.post.japanpost.jp/service/sisho/ , but since I can't read Japanese well, and Google doesn't translate it well either, I'm afraid I could commit some mistake.

The closest Post Office to me will be https://map.japanpost.jp/p/search/dtl/300190375000/

1. Can I safely send to this Post Office, or do I need to choose another one nearby?
2. Would these be correct?

   - Name: My full name (in Latin)
   - Address:

   > 琴似二条郵便局留め (I just added 留め to the Post Office name)
   >
   > 北海道札幌市西区琴似二条５－１－８
   >
   > 063-0812

   - Telephone number: the phone listed in the link above? I won't have a Japanese number!

Comment: So, after your edit, what is the question?

Comment: @fkraiem the updated link has most information I couldn't find before. I don't know how to delete this

Comment: If you wish to have it deleted, you can flag it for a moderator's attention.

Answer (score 4):

In order to answer your questions for others.

Yes, you can send a Yuu-pack and have it delivered to the post office in the manner you described in the question. Regular mail can also be delivered in a similar manner, see image on the link you provided.

If you don't have a phone number you should be able to leave it blank.

Please note that the post office will only hold it for 10 days.

Comment: The problem is that it is an Amazon order, which is likely to be shipped through Yamato or some other shipping company. (In my experience, Amazon Japan uses Japan Post only for books, and even then, only if you choose standard delivery.)

Comment: I once asked my local post office about the possibility of picking up a parcel at that local post office (note that our only common language was broken – broken Japanese and broken English) but the answer was that the only way for me to pick up personally was to go to the city’s main post office, not the small local one. Not sure if that only applies to missed deliveries or if I was just unlucky.

Comment: Undelivered packages are stored at the central post office for a given district, so yes that is where you'd have to go to pick up a package that was undelievered.